# setOnClickListener method can't get EditText value

Tags: android, oncreate

environment: Android Studio 3.1.1

```
public class AddQuestionActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    public Button add_question;
    public EditText question_EditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_question);

        add_question = findViewById(R.id.addquestion);

        question_EditText = findViewById(R.id.question_add);

        final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();

        Log.d("finds","question1:"+question);

        add_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Log.d("finds","question:"+question);
                if (question.length()==0)
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(AddQuestionActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.add_error)
                        .setMessage(R.string.add_blank)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

question's value always empty.

Finally, I find another way 
in *.xml add

```
android:onClick="add_question"
```

in *.java use

```
public void add_question(View v)
    {
}
```

and it works.

I don't understand why setOnClickListener method didn't work?

```
final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
```

should I change this code into the setOnClickListener method ?

Comment: Why don't you put question String inside On-Click!

Comment: Its empty as question string get the value of your edit text when your activity opens and you want latest value of the edit text, so you should check the length inside onClick and also get the text content of editText inside OnClick

Comment: reply:Rahul Chandrabhan: I'm new to android, sometime make stupid mistakes

Comment: It's cool brother, everbody does...even me..LOL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove this

```
final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
```

it only get value 1 time when initial activity.

Move `String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();` into onClick method.

Try this to get current string in edittext when you click button.

```js
        
        add_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
                Log.d("finds","question:"+question);
                if (question.length()==0)
                {
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(AddQuestionActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.add_error)
                        .setMessage(R.string.add_blank)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
```

this line of code is inside your OnCreate() method, so it is called only once when Activity loads.
After adding text to EditText, you clicks the button, but the string "question" contains initial value only; not the updated one.
So , you should call that code after adding text to EditText.or onClick listener of your Button.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

you use

```
final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
```

change to

```
String question = uestion_EditText.getText().toString(); //gets you the question  of edit text
```

**put this line inside onClick()**

like this:

```
     add_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
            Log.d("finds","question:"+question);
            if (question.length()==0)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(AddQuestionActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(R.string.add_error)
                    .setMessage(R.string.add_blank)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                    .show();
            }
        }
    });
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

remove following lines from there and add it into onclick method.

```
final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
Log.d("finds","question1:"+question);
```

here, is the full code of `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_question);

    add_question = findViewById(R.id.addquestion);

    question_EditText = findViewById(R.id.question_add);

    add_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
            Log.d("finds","question1:"+question);

            if (question.length()==0)
            {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(AddQuestionActivity.this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.add_error)
                        .setMessage(R.string.add_blank)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                        .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

**NOTE :** You are trying to get edittext value out side the onclick , it will be always inside it !

`final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();`

```
 add_question.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    final String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("finds","question:"+question);
                    if (question.length()==0)
                    {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(AddQuestionActivity.this)
                            .setTitle(R.string.add_error)
                            .setMessage(R.string.add_blank)
                            .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, null)
                            .setNeutralButton(R.string.cancel, null)
                            .show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String question = question_EditText.getText().toString();
```

put this line inside `onClick()`